# Fetch Data from express server via sweetalert

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sweetalert

Hey i made an webserver with nodejs and express
if i sent a request to ip/test it give me text via res.send('test)

i want to fetch this text via sweetalert but it always fail :/

The JavaScript Code:

```
const ipAPI = 'http://ip:port/test'

Swal.queue([{
title: '',
confirmButtonText: 'Click me',
showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
preConfirm: () => {
    return fetch(ipAPI)
    .then(response => response.html())
    .then(data => Swal.insertQueueStep(data))
    .catch(() => {
        Swal.insertQueueStep({
        icon: 'error',
        title: ':('
            })
        })
    }
}])
```

And the Nodejs Express Code:

```
app.post('/test', function(req, res){
    res.send(globalServerCount);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer:

```
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
    res.send(globalServerCount);
});
```